# How to constrain a table linking two tables in many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, many-to-many, constraints

Say I have the following tables and columns:

```
comp: 
    id, 
    model

dvd: 
    id, 
    model

comp2dvd: 
    id, 
    id_comp, 
    id_dvd
```

A computer can have multiple dvd drives, even of the same model, and a dvd drive can appear in multiple computers. How do I make it so that comp2dvd table can have only existing comp and dvd ids?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot normally have a foreign key reference without an enforcing index which identifies a column or combination of columns as unique (such as, but not limited to, a primary key)

comp should have id as primary key

dvd should have id as primary key

comp2dvd should have id as primary key

comp2dvd should have id_comp as foreign key references(comp.id)

comp2dvd should have id_dvd as foreign key references(dvd.id)

DO NOT let comp2dvd have a unique index or constraint on the pair of columns (id_comp, id_dvd), since you need duplicates for computers with multiple identical drives

Answer (score 1):

Why not just go with a straight join table?  You could add a constraint on the join table to only allow the use of one DVDID + computer combination.

```
Computer  -----> CompDVD  <------ DVD --------> Model
ID               CompID           ID            ID
                 DVDID
```

Comment: I noted that a computer can have two instances of the same dvd drive. The dvd table holds just unique dvd models.

Comment: Well, you said "computer can have multiple dvd drives, even of the same model" but I assume each computer's actual physical drives are unique, surely?

Comment: I'd put the unique DVD models into a separate table, as illustrated

Comment: @Gromul this would work - The join table enforces a many to many relationship and you just put a constraint on each ID in the CompDVD so that it exists in the appropriate table +1

Answer (score 0):

By adding foreign keys to id_comp and id_dvd?

Comment: This would work if the link table had just id_comp and id_dvd, but that doesn't work for me. If I try to add foreign keys, I get this error: The columns in table 'dvd' do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint.